# How to attach document to an Excel column using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have an requirment as follows:

I have 100 folders- namely `74555Attachment`,`55874Attachment` like this. Now each folder contains maximum 5-6 files(.pdf,.csv etc).now i want to attach them to a excel from the folder to an excel column.

```
TicketNumber               file1           file2

 74555                    abc.pdf          tt.csv
 55874                     ab.pdf          tt.docx
```

Can it be done using Ruby?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using ruby file operations

or gems like "spreadsheet", "CSV" to handle excel file. you need to use regex to separate number from file name.